# x.reshape([1,28,28,1]) reshaping meaning

Tags: python, numpy

I can not understand what this reshaping actually do with an array of 28*28.

**the code is:**

```
x.reshape([1,28,28,1])
```

Comment: It makes a new array, a `view`, with the same data, but a different `shape`. That's all.  The new array will display differently, require changes when indexing, and `broadcast` differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reshape - as the name suggests - reshapes your array into an array of different shape.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(28*28)
>>> x.shape
(784,)
>>> y = x.reshape(28,28)
>>> y.shape
(28, 28)
>>> z = y.reshape([1, 28, 28, 1])
>>> z.shape
(1, 28, 28, 1)
```

A shape of `1` implies that the respective dimension has a length of `1`. This is most useful when working with broadcasting, as the array will be repeated along that dimension as needed.

```py
>>> a = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(3, 1)
>>> b = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1, 3)
>>> a * b
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

Another use is to differentiate between row and column vectors, which you can understand as matrices of shape `[1, X]` or `[X, 1]` respectively.

```py
>>> row_vector = np.array([1, 2, 3]).reshape(1,3)
>>> row_vector
array([[1, 2, 3]])
>>> column_vector = np.array([1,2,3]).reshape(3,1)
>>> column_vector
array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```